# 'let him vent out his malevolence/rancor'? matching idiom?

Tags: idiom-requests

I believe an example will serve best to explain it,
so if someone has been extremely tolerant with smb or a group of people over a long period of time, until no more can be beared and emotions flood atop. So consequently he can no longer constrain himself and lets out all accumulated bitter humiliations, belittlement, abuse and maltreatment.

We say something like, 'vent out his malice/malevolence/rancor'.
It is beyond expressing yourself, rather taking out all the pain that person has suffered.

Or as a question 'have you vent out your rancor now'? I.e. do you feel better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**vent your spleen**

> Meaning: If you vent your spleen, you express your anger.
>
> For example: •The company's shareholders were angry, and they used the
>   annual general meeting as an opportunity to vent their spleen on the
>   board members.
>
> •Amy felt she had been badly treated by the media, so she took the
>   chance to vent her spleen during the interview.
>
> Origin: The spleen is an organ in the body near the stomach. In
>   European medicine from the Middle Ages until the nineteenth century,
>   the spleen was thought to be the source of the "humours" that caused
>   the emotion of anger. Therefore one could expel anger by "venting the
>   spleen".
>
> https://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Idioms/V/vent_your_spleen_244.htm

Comment: +1 @mahpack: That's probably more apt than my suggestion given what you describe. It leans more heavily to expressing anger, whereas you **can** "get something off your chest" angrily, but it can also be done in a calm or even cold manner. (And speaking from experience, cold language can be like cold steel, if used properly.) Venting your spleen on the other hand is almost always done in an angry fashion, which ties to the situation that you describe.

Comment: Hi, Chasly, I am not sure what happened, but hope to see you soon at EL&U. Happy new year!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the expression that fits here is "[Get it off your chest](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/get-something-off-one%27s-chest)". There are other expressions like "[speak your piece](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/say-one%27s-piece)", but those lack the nuance of having bottled up something for a while and finally releasing it.

Answer (score 1):

- **blowing off steam**

Think of a whistling teapot. No steam escapes until the pressure is enough to force steam through the spout-lid.

Answer (score 0):

I have always liked "spitting venom" to describe a violent verbal expression of negative emotion.